# Highchart, I want to fill between some values(point to point). in areaspline chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm using HighChart.
I want to fill color to part of area for areaspline chart (or any type chart).

Like in this image:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/gFZO8.png]

How can I do that?

Comment: That's what the "area" part in "areaspline" does... Try changing it to "spline" and tell us what happens. You do want, or you don't want? Question says one thing, graphic linked says another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two series, first spline and second  with area.

```
series: [{
            data: [3, 4, 3]
        }, {
            type: 'areaspline',
            data: [null,null,3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4]
        }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7wSuT/